# Python Turtle Create Horizontal Bar Chart

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I need to create Bar chart horizontally using Python library Turtle. How can i achieve that. I have a sample for Vertical Graphs and it is working perfectly fine but i need to do the same for Horizontal Graphs, and show the value in horizontal.

This url has perfect help for vertical bar chart

http://students.washington.edu/xiongsy/zoekurt/blog/?p=399

How can i achieve my requirements with this code.

Comment: How do you feel about using a library that's actually designed to display charts, so you don't have to manually draw every rectangle yourself? Like Matplotlib, for example.

Comment: that's good suggestion but i want to try it with turtle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical bar chart example you have is not great code (too many fixed assumptions.) Regardless, I've done a crude job of inverting the x and y axes to make it into a horizontal bar chart example for you:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 12
FONT = ("Arial", FONT_SIZE, "normal")

COLORS = ['#CC9933', '#6699CC', '#CC3399', '#996633', '#336699', '#0099CC', '#FF9999', '#CC0066', '#99CC00', '#CC3399', '#009933']

print("Welcome to the Turtle Charter!")

### Prompt for input ###

title = input("What is the title of your chart? ")

n = 1
data = {}

while True:
    label = input('Input data label {}: '.format(n))
    if label == '':
        break

    while True:
        value = input('Input data value {}: '.format(n))

        try:
            value = float(value)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter only numeric value.')

    data[label] = value
    n += 1

print("Generating graph...")

### Create and Setup the Window ###
xmax = max(data.values())
window = Screen()
window.title(title)
height = 130 * (len(data) + 1)  # (the space between each bar is 30, the width of each bar is 100)
window.setup(600, height)  # specify window size (width is 600)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-225, -(height / 2) + 50)
turtle.pendown()

# draw x-axis and ticks
xtick = 400 / 7

for i in range(1, 8):
    turtle.forward(xtick)
    xv = float(xmax / 7 * i)
    turtle.write('%.1f' % xv, move=False, align="center", font=FONT)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.backward(10)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.setpos(-225, -(height / 2) + 50)
turtle.left(90)

# draw bar and fill color
pixel = xmax / 400
recs = []  # bar height
for value in data.values():
    recs.append(value / pixel)

for i, rec in enumerate(recs):
    turtle.color('black')
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.forward(rec)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(50 - FONT_SIZE/2)
    turtle.write('  ' + str(rec * pixel), move=False, align="left", font=FONT)
    turtle.forward(50 + FONT_SIZE/2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(rec)
    turtle.color(COLORS[i % len(COLORS)])
    turtle.end_fill()
    turtle.right(90)

turtle.setpos(-225, -(height / 2) + 50)
turtle.color('black')

# draw y-axis and labels
turtle.pendown()

for key in data:
    turtle.forward(30)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.write('  ' + key, move=False, align="left", font=FONT)
    turtle.forward(90)

turtle.forward(30)

### Tell the window to wait for the user to close it ###
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: There is one problem to it. Where there are a lot number of graphs then they move upper to the screen, and i can't see them. How can i fix that ?

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar, this is only an example, not a custom tailored solution.  You could embed the drawing in a scrolling canvas -- search SO on how to do this.  Another/additional approach is to narrow the bars and gaps as the number of items increases.

Comment: I did narrow the bars and also added scrolling. But there is one thing that i am not able to understand, they when i increase the number of bars the top tip goes further down

Comment: top tip of y-axis